# What is the point of dependency injection as used in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

I have been reading the book Spring in Action for a few weeks now to learn about the spring framework. I have about 2 years of programming experience mostly in java with some distractions here and there in Ruby and Python.

After reading the first few chapters, I didn't quite get what the big deal is about dependency injection in spring. I was expecting a AHAAA moment but didn't quite experience that yet. I'm sure I'm missing something important.

Why would I want to wire my beans in xml rather than instantiating them the good old way with the `= new myclass();`

I understand I can wire beans in the xml via constructor args and properties as well as configure datasources in spring so that I can hide away connection details in an xml file. But  why? There is more to this especially when it comes to good software design. Can some one explain the big deal?

Comment: You should certainly read this article - http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html

Comment: Looks like you have read an old Spring in Action Book. Since Spring 3.0, there is not so much bean definition left in the xml.

Comment: I did read Spring 3. You gotta help me by explaining how little xml configuration = inversion of control. How can that be?

Comment: Ralph, could you explain? How the xml has decreased in spring 3. How does autowiring allow decoupling?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Three Words: **INVERSION OF CONTROL**

In a nutshell:
As soon as you instantiate "the good old way" you create tight coupling, e.g.: your controller depends on a specific template engine, your entities on a concrete database layer, etc. And that's something you want to prevent and where the dependency injection container (DIC) comes in very handy. It manages your services and you don't really have to care anymore about specific implementations as long as those implement the same interface.

Imagine a simple storage layer class called `InMemoryLayer` that gets instantiated by you when you need it. Now you want to switch it for an awesome new open-source GitHub solution called `SuperSecretRemoteCloudLayer`. Normally you would now hit "Search and Replace" in your IDE of choice and replace all occurrences of `InMemoryLayer` with the `SuperSecretRemoteCloudLayer`. But that's not handy and quite error-prone, why would you want to do all that hard work by hand? The DIC can do that for you and all *you* need to take care of, is that both `*Layer` implement the same interface (so your application won't break).

Comment: Well said. If we use the anotation, Again we have to search in IDE and find the interface and It has to be change. I am not convinced. what is your view?

Comment: Is another more minor benefit this?:  Explicitly calling constructors in the "Good old way" prone to refactor even when the same implementation is used, but has and update to its constructor params?  If the constructor gets an added param, and DI is used, then that constructor's class just needs to autowire the new param, and no explicit constructor call refactor needed?  (reference: "Changing the signature of the Person constructor" at http://www.javacreed.com/why-should-we-use-dependency-injection/)

Comment: In the case of switching InMemoryLayer with SuperSecretRemoteCloudLayer, I can simply instantiate the storage layer once at put its reference as a public static member in certain. If I do it, I will have to change it only once in the place where the storage layer is instantiated.

Answer (score 6):

Spring's big deal is more about dependency injection, not XML-based configuration. As others have noted, Spring has been moving away from XML-based configuration. But DI is core to Spring.

The a-ha is that DI offers a different model for linking components together. Instead of components creating each other directly (and thus being tightly coupled), the components stop doing that, and you inject the linkages from a central location. It turns out that this helps with testing and transaction management in particular.

Answer (score 5):

You don't truly appreciate Spring until you've had to do things the hard way.  The hard way being maintaining multiple large projects without a coherent framework.  If you have 4 big enterprise wide applications that all have their own way of starting themselves, and managing resources, you're in for a headache.  If you know that each application uses spring, then just look for the application context xml!  This also makes it incredibly easy to setup a new context for different environments, and test cases, all without mucking up your code base.